# Tikz positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

How do you position a node more precisely than left of, right of?

```
\node[above =3 cm of node1,node distance=3.5cm] (node2){};
```

For example, how do you say that I want 3mm to the left and 4 mm above a certain node (or at a certain angle and distance alternatively)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the positioning library, you have the fairly flexible syntax demonstrated here:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A){A};
  \node [above left = 3mm and 4mm of A] (B){B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For positioning nodes at an a distance and angle of another node: TikZ can handle polar coordinates, so this should be straightfoward too, but I'm having a brainfreeze on how precisely to do it in the best way...

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this, with xshift and yshift, and also positions using relative placement with distances, placing the nodes precisely w.r.t the starting node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
     \node[rectangle, draw=black] (node1) {N1};
     \node[rectangle, draw=black,xshift=2cm, yshift=2cm, at=(node1)] (node2) {N2};
     \node[below right=1cm and 1cm of node1, rectangle, draw=black] (node3) {N3};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]